# Material UI - Switch Button the individual data according to status

Tags: reactjs, api, material-ui, use-state

Here is my state,

```
    const [partners, setPartners] = useState([
        {
            accessKeyId: "abc123",
            partnerName: "karta",
            status: "active"
        },
        {
            accessKeyId: "qwe112",
            partnerName: "karta",
            status: "inactive"
        },
        {
            accessKeyId: "zxc358",
            partnerName: "special",
            status: "inactive"
        },

    ])

    const [isActive, setActive] = useState({
                                            active: true,
                                            inactive: false
                                        });
```

How to make the switch button is true when status is active and button is false when the status is inactive? and how to make it toggle the status when I click the switch button.
[image]

```
{partners.map((partner, index) => (
    <TableRow key={partner.accessKeyId}>
        <TableCell align="left">{partner.accessKeyId} </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">********* </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{partner.partnerName} </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">
            <FormGroup>
                <FormControlLabel                  
                    value={index}
                    onChange={() => handleChange(index)}
                    control={<Switch
                        value={isActive}
                        checked={`isActive.${partner.status}`}
                        />}
                         />
              </FormGroup>
```

Comment: to set the switch button active or inactive set the checked into checked={partner.status === 'active' ? true : false}

Answer (score 2):

Please find the updated code below:

**#Handle Change Function**

```
const handleChange = (keyId) => {
      const newData = partners.map(item => {
        if(item.accessKeyId === keyId) {
          item.status = item.status === 'active' ? 'inactive' : 'active';
        }
        return item;
      })
      setPartners(newData);
    }
```

Now the JSX part in which how you will embed onChange function

```
    {partners.map((partner, index) => (
        <TableRow key={partner.accessKeyId}>
            <TableCell align="left">{partner.accessKeyId} </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">********* </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">{partner.partnerName} </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">
                <FormGroup>
                    <FormControlLabel                  
                        value={index}
                        control={<Switch
                            checked={partner.status === 'active'}
                            onChange={() => handleChange(partner.accessKeyId)}
                            />}
                        label={partner.status}
                             />
                  </FormGroup>
```

I hope this may be helpful to you.

Kindly, let me know in case of any concerns.

Comment: Hello Prateek, thank you for giving me an additional idea. The value of {partner.status} is either "active or inactive" so the "checked" properties will not return an on/off button need a boolean value "true or false", How to make the value of {partner.status} is make a boolean "true or false" because the value is "active and inactive". Thank you

Comment: Hello Prateek, I tried and test the code that you suggest, but the state is not changing when I refresh the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `isActive` variable? If I understand the question correctly, You can use `partners` status instead, changing it to `isActive` boolean property.

```
<FormGroup>
    <FormControlLabel                  
        value={index}
        id={partner.accessKeyId}
        onChange={() => handleChange(id)}
        control={<Switch
            value={partner.isActive}
            checked={partner.isActive}
            />}
     />
</FormGroup>
```

to toggle status in `handleChange` function you may copy `Partners` array and change `isActive` property based on `accessKeyId`

```
const clonedPartners = partners.map(el => {...el});
const updatedPartners = clonedPartners(el => {
    if (el.accessKeyId === id){
        el.isActive = !el.isActive;
    }
}
```

and to update `Partners` use `setPartners(updatedPartners)`

Comment: Hello Alex, thank you for giving me an additional idea. The value of {partner.status} is either "active or inactive" so the "checked" properties will not return an on/off button need a boolean value "true or false", How to make the value of {partner.status} is make a boolean "true or false" because the value is "active and inactive". Thank you

Comment: I have edited the answer a little. Instead of {partners.status} you can set property {isActive} (true/false).